# Strange type resolution in C# .NET 5 WebAssembly

Tags: c#, .net-5, webassembly, uno-platform

I have a Uno Platform app, built on the .NET 5 on WebAssembly.

I have a library, that constructs a `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs` every time a Toast Notification is clicked, and calls the `OnActivated` method of `Application.Current`. For some reasons, the class has no constructors visible, both through code, and through Reflection (`GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Count()` returns 0) although one is declared [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/d555e1316e331610f64a3d81a07804bd66a1ab89/src/Uno.UWP/ApplicationModel/Activation/ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs.cs#L7).

So I created the object using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`, and initialized each fields using reflection. However, after that strange things start to happen.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Prints True.
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType() == typeof(ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs));
    // Gives a valid object.
    var obj1 = (ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)e;
    // Prints False.
    Console.WriteLine(e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs);
    // Gives null
    var obj2 = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;
}
```

I suspect that `FormatterServices.GetUnitializedObject` must be doing something bad, but when I tried to replicate that using normal .NET 5, [nothing happened](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIMeKh). The types are resolved normally.

So what am I doing wrong here? I know that abusing reflection and using `FormatterServices` for stuff other than deserialization is not nice, but this is the only way I know as I have to touch some internal functions to replicate the behavior in UWP from an external library.

Comment: I think that the constructor is simply not there, as it is not used anywhere and it is internal, so the linker removes it. However - I am curious - how does the external library call the `OnActivated` method? Would it be possible for you to create a custom class implementing `IActivatedEventArgs` and use that instead?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes, it is internal, but it is not guaranteed that it cannot be used anywhere, because as far as I know, `Uno.UI` has a bunch of `InternalsVisibleTo` attributes.  

About the `OnActivated`, as it is `protected`, there is no way that the external library could call it from code: I use reflection to both create a instance of the `EventArgs` and to call `OnActivated`.

Comment: @MartinZikmund And as cross-platform code is expecting `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastActivatedEventArgs`, I doubt that a custom class would work. And even if it worked, I would still have to mess up with reflection to call `OnActivated` anyway.

Comment: Is BindingFlags.Private a typo for BindingFlags.NonPublic (which is what you need for internal)?  I think it must be?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the linker removing the unused internal constructor to decrease the resulting assembly size. You can prevent this by adding the following in the `LinkerConfig.xml` file in the WASM project:

```xml
<assembly fullname="Uno">
  <type fullname="Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs" />
</assembly>
```

You can now confirm that the constructor is available:

```cs
var constructors = typeof(ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs).GetConstructors(
   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Console.WriteLine(constructors.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've still didn't understand how `is` and `as` works on .NET 5 WASM, when two   types that are confirmed as the same using `GetType`, and succeeds using a classic cast but fails when using `is` and `as`.